# JavaScript - getter function vs constructor - which is executed first?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I need to know which is executed first in the component and execution order.

Get is called before constructor  or Constructor gets called first. I am unable to put console in Get accessor.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor called on App Component');
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(' onChanges called on App Component');
  }

  clicked() {
    console.log('red');
  }

  get name(): string {
    return 'sahir';
    console.log('called get method');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor will always be called first. You need an instance of the class in order to access a property.

Also, the `console.log` you put on the getter will never run since it is after a `return` statement.